# how to make bottom border gradient?

Tags: html, css, border, gradient

EXAMPLE:

[image]

Hello i need help with creating the bottom border with gradient and transparent edges.

How could I go about creating this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a pseudo element for this, allowing higher browser support than a border-image..

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #222;
}
hr {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  border: 0;
}
hr:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
.demo1:before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
.demo2:before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(179, 220, 237, 0) 0%, rgba(41, 184, 229, 1) 50%, rgba(188, 224, 238, 0) 100%);
}
.demo3:before{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(182,224,38,0) 0%,rgba(177,222,39,1) 50%,rgba(171,220,40,0) 100%); 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<hr class="demo1" />
<br />
<hr class="demo2" />
<br />
<hr class="demo3" />
```

**please note**

- prefixing here has been automatically included via the prefix-free script.
- I've used a `hr` element for demo purposes only. however, this effect can be used on all elements that support the use of pseudo elements (i.e. `div`, `a`, `p`, etc)